# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build Flutter - Providers

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm trying to use fl_chart dependency to add some charts
but every time I found this error `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build`

```
    class PieChartSample2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const PieChartSample2({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PieChart2State();
}

List<String> gouvr = [
  "Ariana",
  "Béja",
  "Ben Arous",
  "Bizerte",
  "El Kef",
  "Gabes",
];

class PieChart2State extends State {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<RecProvider>(context, listen: false).reclamationList.isEmpty
        ? Provider.of<RecProvider>(context, listen: false).getPosts()
        : {};

    super.initState();
  }

  int touchedIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1.3,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 18,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1,
              child: PieChart(
                PieChartData(
                  pieTouchData: PieTouchData(
                    touchCallback: (FlTouchEvent event, pieTouchResponse) {
                      setState(() {
                        if (!event.isInterestedForInteractions ||
                            pieTouchResponse == null ||
                            pieTouchResponse.touchedSection == null) {
                          touchedIndex = -1;
                          return;
                        }
                        touchedIndex = pieTouchResponse
                            .touchedSection!.touchedSectionIndex;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  borderData: FlBorderData(
                    show: false,
                  ),
                  sectionsSpace: 0,
                  centerSpaceRadius: 40,
                  sections: showingSections(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

gouvr is the list of governorates, I use it to filter the reclamationlist.
The sections refer to a function called 'showingSections()' returns the List of PieChartSectionData , which uses providers.

```
  List<PieChartSectionData> showingSections() {
    late List<PieChartSectionData> p = [];
    List.generate(24, (i) {
      final random = Random();

      final isTouched = i == touchedIndex;
      final fontSize = isTouched ? 25.0 : 16.0;
      final radius = isTouched ? 60.0 : 50.0;
      const shadows = [Shadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 2)];
      Provider.of<RecProvider>(context, listen: false).getFilteredList(
        selectedCity: gouvr[i],
        selectedStatus: "tous",
        selectedType: "tous",
      );
      if (Provider.of<RecProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .filteredList
          .isNotEmpty) {
        p.add(PieChartSectionData(
          color: Color.fromARGB(
            255,
            random.nextInt(256), // red value
            random.nextInt(256), // green value
            random.nextInt(256), // blue value
          ),
          value: (100 * Provider.of<RecProvider>(context).filteredList.length) /
              Provider.of<RecProvider>(context).reclamationList.length,
          title: gouvr[i],
          radius: radius,
          titleStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: fontSize,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.black,
            shadows: shadows,
          ),
        ));
      }
    });
    return p;
  }
}
```

help me, please

Comment: can you try using Consumer widget on `showingSections`

Answer (score 0):

As the error describes, setState is called before the build function is completed.

You might not see any issue in your UI when this exception hits on debug or local release mode. But exceptions like these display a grey screen or something instead of the desired widget on google play release etc.

It means you try to refresh the page even while the initial widget is loading.

To prevent calling setState during the build method is already in progress, you can check whether your initial widget is mounted correctly before calling setState. To do that, just wrap your setState by if statement like this:

if(mounted){
setState((){

});
}

Comment: it's true i don't habe any UI issues when I run this code... i tried to add mounted and even delete the setstate but still have this error

Comment: @Eya Rais Can you please share your code so that we can debug and provide possible solution?